# Quickbooks Desktop third party API

Tags: api, cloud, desktop-application, quickbooks, connector

Does anyone have any success integrating with Quickbooks Desktop through a third party API at scale, bi-directional and uploaded to the cloud?

We are currently unsatisfied with our existing setup and looking at other options.

Can't mention existing set up due to contractual concerns.

Our main problem is that the third party connector that we use, keeps failing in production environments.